# User Control, Delegate and UpdatePanel Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, delegates

I am currently running up against a problem with the UpdatePanel. One of my pages has two User Controls I'll call A and B.

The User Control A has an UpdatePanel containing several ASP TextBox.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upA" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" style="position: relative;">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <-- content here -->
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The User Control B has an UpdatePanel containing a Panel and an AjaxModalPopup linked to it. In the Panel, there is a Repeater and an ASP button.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upB" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnActivePopupContainer" runat="server" Style="display: none;" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopupContainer" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup modalPopupDraggable" Style="display: none;" Width="750px">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPopup" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlHeader" class="header">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:global, AttentionPopup %>"></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>
                <article>
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptPopup" OnItemDataBound="rptPopup_ItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <-- Content -->
                       </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </article>
                <footer>
                    <div class="or-spacer">
                        <div class="mask"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer">
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlBtnBug">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" CssClass="btn yes" Text="<%$ Resources:global, Ok %>" OnClick="btnOK_Click" />
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>
    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="popupContainer" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="pnlPopupContainer" TargetControlID="btnActivePopupContainer" Drag="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlHeader"></ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
</ContentTemplate>
```

When the user clicks the OK button of the UserControl B, it triggers a delegate that calls a method in the UserControl A that performs updating of some fields and the update method of the UpdatePanel "upA".

The delegate:

```
//Delegate Call When the user clicks the ok Button
popup.okHandler = (x) =>
{
   A.ChooseOpticienCode(x.Value);
};
```

in the UserControl A's code behind:

```
public void ChooseOpticienCode(string code)
{
    <-- some treatments -- >
    upOpticien.Update(); <-- crash here
}
```

When the method upOpticien.Update() is called, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'upOpticien before Render.
```

I don't understand why I get this error. I tried to set the UpdateMode of the UpdatePanel to "Always", the application no longer crashes but the fields are not updated.

ideas ?

Comment: Why are you trying to update the UpdatePanel manually instead of setting a trigger for it?  Regardless, it looks like the error is telling you you cannot run the .Update() method in that part of the page life cycle.  You should try to find/read the documentation on that method.

Comment: I try to update it manually because it's in the code behind that I change the values of all Textbox that the UpdatePanel contains.
So, since the values are modified in the codebehind, no event will launch and therefore triggers are unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to fix my problem. Instead of calling the delegate directly, I must use the InvokeMember function so that the delegate is executed correctly and can edit the various fields and update the UpdatePanel

```
 page.GetType().InvokeMember(OkHandler.Method.Name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, page, new[] { this });
```

(here, OkHandler is my delegate)

However, note that using an anonymous method will not work, it's imperative that the delegate points to a method with a name for InvokeMember works.